# 'TabularLIME' is not defined Azure DataBricks

Tags: machine-learning, python, pyspark, lime

I have just started working on Azure Data bricks.

I am facing some error while running a already created Python NoteBook.

**Here is the code:**

```
import mmlspark
from mmlspark import *

lime = TabularLIME()\
  .setModel(randomForestModel)\
  .setPredictionCol("predict")\
  .setOutputCol("weights")\
  .setInputCol("feat")
lime_model = lime.fit(eng_train_pipe)
lime_model.save('dbfs:/mnt/aimodels/rf-eng-lag-lime')
```

Getting this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2244283784192060> in <module>
      2 from mmlspark import *
      3 
----> 4 lime = TabularLIME()\
      5   .setModel(rfModel)\
      6   .setPredictionCol("prediction")\

NameError: name 'TabularLIME' is not defined
```

Cluster Runtime is :6.5 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

Comment: After trying this also on an **Azure Databricks notebook**, *after installing mmlspark (the default version)*, I also have the same issue:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgC3J.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgC3J.png) It seems to be related to the version of mmlspark (0.01...), and the documentation does not help much to see it at a glance... I also tried to install a more recent version of this in Azure Databricks without success. I think this is an issue more related to stackoverflow by the way :)

Comment: This question is better suited for Stackoverflow, if should be closed but since you added a bounty we are unable to cast close votes.
Anyway, [documentation](https://mmlspark.blob.core.windows.net/docs/1.0.0-rc1/pyspark/_modules/mmlspark/lime/TabularLIME.html) indicates you should use `lime.TabularLIME.TabularLIME` as answered by Brian Spiering

Answer (score 2):

The namespace is incorrect. The correct namespace is [`mmlspark.lime.TabularLIME.TabularLIME`](https://mmlspark.blob.core.windows.net/docs/0.18.1/pyspark/mmlspark.lime.html#module-mmlspark.lime.TabularLIME)

```py
from mmlspark.lime.TabularLIME import TabularLIME
```

Comment: I did that and now the error is "No module named 'mmlspark.lime"